# cumulative sum for rows upto select row number followed by summing up columns matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, cumsum

I am trying to perform following kind of summation on a matrix:

Let's say the matrix is:

```
    mat <- matrix(c(1:5,rep(0,7),c(1:7),rep(0,5),c(1:10), 0,0), 12,3)
```

I want to do cumulative sum on rows up to row numbers 5, 7, 10 for column numbers 1,2,3 respectively. (The real data can have arbitrary number of rows and columns).

For now, I have been using following code:

```
    sum1 <- matrix(rep(0, 36), 12, 3)
    row_index <- c(5,7,10)
    for (k in 1:3) {
      sum1[1:row_index[k], k] <- cumsum(mat[1:row_index[k], k])
    }
    sum1 <- matrix(apply(sum1,1,sum))
```

To start with, I have the matrix and row_index. I want to avoid using the loop as the data has a lot of columns. I am wondering if there is a way to do that.

Comment: To get this straight: you do a `cumsum` on each column independently, but then you `rowsum` across these cumulative sums and flatten the result? (the `apply(sum1, 1, sum)` at the end - you didn't mention this but this is what you are doing?)

Comment: And will the remaining values in a column (that you do *not* `cumsum` over, e.g. indices 6:12 in column 1) *always* be 0, or is that just for the purpose of this example?

Comment: If what @mathematical.coffee is saying is true, you could do something like: `rowSums(apply(replace(mat, mat==0, NA),2,cumsum),na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @mathematical.coffee sorry, i forgot to mention that in the text but yes, you got it right. I want to sum all columns at the end. All the indices which i do no `cumsum` over are ideally supposed to be zero but they could be negative in which case it need to be filtered. So I like the approach of @thelatemail  as it allows me to replace all elements given any condition. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 2):

```
depth <- c(5,7,10)
mapply( function(x,y) cumsum(mat[1:x, y]), depth, seq_along(depth) )

[[1]]
[1]  1  3  6 10 15

[[2]]
[1]  1  3  6 10 15 21 28

[[3]]
 [1]  1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I used a variant of your code and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

First, define a function:

```
sumcolumn <- function(rows, columns, mat){
  cumsum(mat[1:rows, columns])
}
```

then use mapply on your vectors of columns/rows:

```
mapply(sumcolumn, rows = c(5, 7, 10), columns = c(1, 2, 3), MoreArgs = list(mat = mat))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I was looking to get column sums at the end. So, I modified your code and it worked. `sumcolumn <- function(rows, columns, mat){` `return(c(cumsum(mat[1:rows, columns]),rep(0,(nrow(mat)-rows)))) }` `sum1 <- matrix(apply(mapply(sumcolumn, rows = c(5, 7, 10), columns = c(1, 2, 3), MoreArgs = list(mat = mat)),1,sum))` So thanks a lot!